# What money is being exchanged here?

Tags: meaning

In this sentence:

> 他换了1，000美元。

Did he use dollars to exchange for another money or did he use another money and got dollars as a result?

EDIT:
What about:

> 他换了1，000美元的人民币。

Comment: Without context, I'll suppose "他" is a Chinese and then the latter applies.

Comment: it seems the former （ 换句话说 in other words 换衣服 change one's clothes，世上新人换旧人）, convert (currency) into is 把（货币）换成,他换了1，000美元 may simply be "he changed $1,000", he traded $1，000, into what is left unanswered, context may remove any doubt, however it should be kept in mind that 换 can mean "change into", e.g.ichacha, iciba: They told me I needed a new battery. 他们告诉我需要换新电池。 Do you think I need new shocks? 你认为我需要换新的减震器吗？换乘火车 change to a train.

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/what-role-does-%e6%88%90-ch%c3%a9ng-play-in-the-sentence-%e6%88%91%e6%8a%8a%e5%8d%81%e5%9d%97%e7%be%8e%e5%85%83%e6%8d%a2%e6%88%90%e4%ba%ba%e6%b0%91%e5%b8%81/26729#26729 他换了1,000美元 means he exchanged (some other currency) into $1,000 USD

Comment: users were looking in vain for confirmation, they only could see 换成，as mentioned before  换+object is often used in the sense of change into object, another example iciba: As soon as I started in my new job I felt like a new man.

一开始新的工作我就觉得精神振奋,像是换了一个人.
also note 
  

in 如果有人不和您合作，就随时给我们打电话，我会在２０分钟内为您换个新人。

Answer (score 1):

“他换了1，000美元” is not clear; which denomination became what?

他用人民币换了1，000美元。（He changed RMB, bought $ 1000)

他把1000美元换成了人民币。（He changed $ 1000, bought RMB)

Comment: Our any other random currency or cryptocurrency for that matter

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is ambiguous the same way the equivalent English sentence "He exchanged 1000 USD" is ambiguous. In real life, the context will make it sufficiently clear, so this sentence is probably heard a lot. But taken out of context, you will need to clarify by saying "把 currency A 換成 currency B" - exchanged currency A INTO currency B.

Or, another shorter way to express this is “他買了 1000 美元” He exchanged his money INTO USD.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible is He used 6700 rmb to get 1000 dollars.

Comment: Agree, unless the context suggests otherwise. But: the most possible is He used *another currency* to bought 1000 dollar. No one said it's from CNY to USD, only USD is mentioned.